# SQL ignores WHERE statement

Tags: mysql

When I run this SQL query it ignores the date WHERE.

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?  Tried a sub query but that didn't work either!  New to SQL but am a bit stumped by what I thought was a relatively simple query.

```
SELECT c.Customer_No, c.Name, c.Lat, c.Lon, o.Order_ref, o.Currency, 
    o.Salesperson_code, o.Date, sum(o.Amount) as order_total, 
    count(DISTINCT o.Order_ref) as order_count  
FROM navision_orders o, navision_customers c 
WHERE c.Customer_No = o.Customer_No
    and o.Date > '2013-01-09' 
    and o.Date < '2014-01-01' 
GROUP BY c.Name
ORDER BY order_total DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Why do you think it is not working ?

Comment: Please stop using non ANSI standard `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using your `WHERE` clause as you should be using a `JOIN` clause. So try this:

```
FROM navision_orders o
INNER JOIN navision_customers c ON c.Customer_No = o.Customer_No
Where o.Date > '2013-01-09' and o.Date < '2014-01-01'
```

Comment: How can it help? Especially with redundant comma after ` navision_orders o,` . I agree ANSI `JOIN` is much better and clear syntax than join condition in `WHERE`, but why `LEFT JOIN`, not `INNER JOIN` here ?

Comment: @a1ex07 I realized the first issue and fixed it, second one might just be my T-SQL comming in. So `INNER JOIN` would work but `LEFT JOIN` wouldn't? I'll fix that.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN ` may work as well - I can't tell for sure until OP posts more details about the problem. But condition in `WHERE` as in the question corresponds `INNER JOIN `, no `LEFT`.

Comment: Thanks for your very quick help! As you can tell I am a bit of a beginner with SQL! Should I simply replace your code with my section after the FROM?

Comment: @user1978239 Keep in your `SELECT` part, replace your `FROM` and `WHERE` with my code, and then keep in the `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, and then `LIMIT` code.